# Prevent OpenJPA from flushing until commit time

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere, openjpa

I'm using OpenJPA 1.2.3, the default version that comes with WebSphere 7.0.

What I'm trying to do is to prevent OpenJPA from flushing until commit time. I thought this would easily be accomplished by setting the Entity Manager flush mode type to FlushModeType.COMMIT. Below is the code that get the Entity Manager and set the flush mode.

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager(String name) {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = (EntityManager) this.context.lookup("java:comp/env/" + name);
        em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to get EntityManager for " + name, e);
    }
    return em;
}
```

I've also added the

```
<property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="false"/>
```

property to my persistence.xml, but OpenJPA still flushes before executing queries to the database.

Below is an example error message, I get during a flush before executing a query. I know why I get that error, and it can easily be fixed, but due a limiting in the existing custom logics (and it can't be modified), I need OpenJPA to defer flushing until commit time.

```
2015-03-10 21:43:45.622 class org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException:
Encountered unmanaged object in persistent field
"com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxWorkorder.xxxBundle" during flush.
However, this field does not allow cascade persist. Set the cascade attribute for this field to CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL (JPA annotations) or "persist" or "all" (JPA orm.xml), or enable cascade-persist globally, or
manually persist the related field value prior to flushing. You cannot flush unmanaged objects or graphs that have persistent associations to unmanaged objects.
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlushPC(SingleFieldManager.java:754)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:594)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:562)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.SingleFieldManager.preFlush(SingleFieldManager.java:478)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.preFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:2829)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.PDirtyState.beforeFlush(PDirtyState.java:37)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.StateManagerImpl.beforeFlush(StateManagerImpl.java:960)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1967)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flushSafe(BrokerImpl.java:1927)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.flush(BrokerImpl.java:1698)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.isInMemory(QueryImpl.java:956)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:796)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:775)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:771)
 at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.execute(DelegatingQuery.java:517)
 at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:255)
 at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:317)
```

My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
 version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="MaxPU" transaction-type="JTA">
   <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
   <jta-data-source>jdbc/MaximoDatabase</jta-data-source>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundleStatus</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.DomainObject</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxWorkorder</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxWr</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxAcknowledge</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundleAppl</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundleEvent</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundleAsset</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundleMemo</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundlePort</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxChildDomain</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxJobPlan</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxOrderErCd</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxOrderErLog</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxOrderRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxOrderRuleFld</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxStatusRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxVentyxMsgCntrl</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxVentyxMsgCntrlData</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundHist</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxDataEditRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxExportMstr</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxGoprtyRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxJobValRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxPrintLoc</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxWoHist</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxWorkgroup</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxCoprtyRule</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.XxxBundle</class>
   <class>com.xxx.yyy.common.model.domain.Labor</class>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <properties>
     <!-- OpenJPA specific properties -->
     <property name="openjpa.TransactionMode" value="managed"/>
     <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryMode" value="managed"/>
     <property name="openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary" value="oracle"/>
     <property name="openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries" value="false"/>
   </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: () I don't think you really can. The problem with preventing flushs before queries is, that you would have to merge the state of the DB with your in memory representation and then perform the query in memory. Otherwise you will potentially have stale data in your query result. Depending on the size of the DB it is simply not feasable to load everything in memory. May I ask why you are trying to avoid the flush()?

Comment: I found that setting openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries to false and openjpa.IgnoreChanges to true seems to prevent OpenJPA from flushing before queries (using native queries). There are two reasons:

Comment: I found that setting openjpa.FlushBeforeQueries to false and openjpa.IgnoreChanges to true seems to prevent OpenJPA from flushing before queries (using native queries). There are two reasons:
1. database constraints on incomplete data at flush time before queries.
2. be able to retrieve unmodified data from the database during processing as if I'm doing the retrieval via another transaction.

Comment: Ok. The first requirement can be solved via deferred constraints, i.e. they are checked at commit time only. At least Oracle has this feature and we also use it quite extensively. Your second feature is somewhat strange to me, but I'm sure you have your reasons for it. Not sure how to solve that though, as it also defeats the purpose of transaction isolation.